# kotlin + espresso: No activities found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, android-espresso

Coming back to Android dev after a year and I'm all confused on espresso again -_-

I'm just trying to setup a simple espresso test and it fails saying:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No activities found. Did you forget to launch the activity by calling getActivity() or startActivitySync or similar?

and indeed, I don't see the app being launched. Here is the code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class EfficioTest {
    @get:Rule @JvmField var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    private fun getActivity() = activityRule.activity

    @Test fun testInitState() {
        onView(withId(R.id.store_spinner)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

MainActivity is in the manifest and is working fine when launching using the launcher.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it! Changed:

```
@get:Rule @JvmField var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

To:

```
 @Rule @JvmField var activityRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

(removed get:)

Comment: Hello, Geob-o-matic. Please, consider marking your own answer as correct to help others. :)

Answer (score 2):

For me

```
 @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)
```

has worked